# Running Ionic serve on CMD: "Ionic not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, command-prompt

I am trying to run Ionic Serve through command prompt and have done the following steps:

1. Cloned the ionic project from my teams directory
2. Installed node JS: it is version 5_10
3. Ran `npm install -g ionic cordova`
4. Selected the cloned directory and typed "ionic serve"

The error I got was "Ionic not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

In other SO posts, a user suggested the following.

> First check: `npm config get prefix`
>
> In my case It wasn't set to `/usr/local but in /usr/Roaming`
>
> So to fix it, use:  `npm config set prefix`

But this did not work for me, perhaps, I was in the wrong directory.

Can anyone suggest how to get the command Ionic Serve to work?

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 7

Comment: I tried doing exactly the same steps in Git Shell. Same error: The term "ionic" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script, file, or operable program.

Comment: You have to add global node_modules to PATH